# Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.getMetaData()" because "<parameter2>" is null

Tags: java, intellij-idea, h2

Hi I am using an H2 database for a tutorial I am following online.

I downloaded the H2 database jar file and put it in a lib file like so:

[image: Click here]

I also created a library in my project structure like so:

[image: Click here]

Main code to test:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    // write your code here
        Server.main();
        System.out.println("DB Launched");
    }
}
```

Then I created a db folder - and when I ran my application I entered the path to the DB folder in my project solution for the 'JDBC url'. I followed all of the instructions for the course.

Then when I connected I got the following error (in the web application):

[image: See error]

```
Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.getMetaData()" because "<parameter2>" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.getMetaData()" because "<parameter2>" is null
    at org.h2.bnf.context.DbContents.readContents(DbContents.java:154)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.tables(WebApp.java:698)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:225)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:170)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:134)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:90)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I followed all instructions... I do not know why I am getting this error - I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you,

tomkt,

Comment: You seem to have not shown us the relevant code. Is it your code calling `getMetaData`, or are you calling other code that provokes that error. Or are you saying this error occurs with this "web application"? Is that the GUI provided by H2, or something else you are running. Voting to close as not providing enough info to debug the situation.

Comment: @BasilBourque i do not agree with you on this - i literally have NO code in my application. All I've done is configure the library and called 'Server.main'.

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to run H2 as a separate database server? Or are you trying to embed H2 within your app?

Comment: @BasilBourque i am trying to embed this into my app. I am following the java reflection api course on Pluralsight. I followed instructions as the author did. I am creating a custom hibernate-like ORM mapper with reflection.. But I haven't written a line of code yet except for the 'main' method code.

Comment: I am no expert on H2, but I have used it for demos and experimenting. When embedding, the database engine automatically starts and creates the initial database files when you use the database URL to make a connection in JDBC. I have shown this in many examples here on Stack Overflow. Where are you getting instructions for calling `Server.main`? I have never seen that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the class they ask you to paste in the file name to the JDBC file on the H2 console, but he doesn't show that you need to leave the front items...

So it should be jdbc:h2:C:\your file path

If you are missing the jdbc:h2 at the front of the field it fails with the message you have above
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsk8e.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete the "jdbc:h2:" at the beginning. I was following the same course and found my problem. Just replace the ~/test part. So it should look something like "jdbc:h2:D:/..."

Comment: At the beginning of *what*? I don't see a URI in his question other than the path to his class, `C:\...`. Are you saying he needs to edit the entry in the library definition?